# SwiftUI - wrapping Button in a view, to create a custom button

Tags: button, swiftui

I'm trying to create my own version of Button, by wrapping it in a view and thus opening up the ability to add more features / hide styling modifiers. I know this doesn't bring benefits, and that ButtonStyles are powerful. But in the interests of super clean code, I am intrigued as to how it can be achieved.

In it's most stripped back form, I would like to write something like (based on Button's own signature):

```
struct MyCustomButton: View {
    let action : () -> Void
    let contents : () -> PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration.Label

    var body : some View {
        Button(action: self.action) {
            self.contents()
        }
    }
}
```

Yet when I try and use it...

```
struct MyView : View {
    var body : some View {
        MyCustomButton(action: { doSomething() }) {
            Text("My custom button")
        }
    }
}
```

...I get the following compilation error: Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type 'PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration.Label'

Answer (score 8):

Have figured this out:

```
struct NewButton<Content: View> : View {
    let content : ()-> Content
    let action: () -> Void

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.content = content
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.action) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change `Button`, by SwiftUI design intention it is just needed to provide custom `ButtonStyle`, like in below example.

```
struct ScaleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let bgColor: Color
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(bgColor)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 5 : 1)
    }
}

struct DemoScaleButtonStyle: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { }) {
            Text("Button")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }.buttonStyle(ScaleButtonStyle(bgColor: Color.red))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - I know that one can use ButtonStyles. Yet I want to go further - based on some work I did in React, where one could wrap a view in another view, and add functionality, not just styling. I also know there are ViewModifiers, but their syntax doesn't feel as natural. If I was to think about the generic problem, how could one write their own "HStack", and keep the syntax style, not the trailing .modifier(HStack()) one we have today.